# ISP gave me 3 ppoe accounts for 3 dedicated IPs, what kind of router do I need?

Tags: networking, router, isp, fiber, pppoe

I made an optic fiber ISP contract that included 1 dedicated IP addresses and 2 additional dedicated IP addresses, now when they gave me the 3 IPs I see I have actually 3 different ppoe accounts.

Is there a reliably gigabit wired router that can have multiple ppoe accounts ? 
Or is there a certain protocol name that I should look for ?

ISP provided this fiber optic router/device "Fiberhome AN5506-02-FG" and they said to bridge from that for the additional PPOE accounts. But I want a cleaner solution and I wonder if this single device could work: "MikroTik RB2011UiAS-IN", not sure if the fiber connection on the MikroTik does the same thing as my current device, but it should support 3 ppoe accounts.

Comment: What bandwidth will you have there? If more than 300mbps simplex, then rb2011 CPU may be too weak AFAIR.

Comment: I didn't notice the comment, the bandwidth is `1000 Mbps / 500 Mbps` down/up.

Comment: Then the CPU of the rb2011 will be your bottleneck of your total capable bandwidth till ~330-350 [mbps], simplex. I mean ie. routing or software switching.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can find, the router you have seems to be based on GPON Fiber.

Apparently Mikrotik do a GPON SFP module that will work in any of their routers that has an SPF port. https://mikrotik.com/product/SFPONU

It's very strange to be given 3 PPPoE accounts for additional IP addresses though, and I'm not 100% certain how you'll configure the router to make use of them. (Creating the 3 PPPoE client interfaces will be easy, I'm just not sure about the routing side)

Comment: @Matt, It'll work, with source based policy routing.

Comment: Well, it works by mounting a switch from their GPON modem (to multiply the ethernet ports) and then I can connect 3 different computers and I can configure the PPOE accounts on the computers individually. It's not bad but it was cleaner with a router that makes the PPOE connections and keeps them on.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the Ubiquiti's [Edgerouter series](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#edgemax) for multiple pppoe.

Configurations you may be interested in are on [Ubiquiti's community support site](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeRouter/Multiple-PPPoE-on-the-same-physical-interface-don-t-route/td-p/2107217) and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubiquiti/comments/6o3c57/edge_router_pro_bt_pppoe_internet_with_multiple/).

The Ubiquiti support community is robust and quick to respond.  Products are a good value; I get Gb throughput, even on my [$49 low-end model](https://www.ubnt.com/edgemax/edgerouter-x/).  I'm not a paid endorser, just a small business IT provider who's had good experiences with Ubiquiti.

Answer (score 1):

Since product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here as well as on most SE sites, I understand your question as "What *kind* of router do I need?"

Any professional-grade router should be able to establish and maintain several WAN sessions. When checking out a potential purchase you should have a plan on how you want to split your traffic/sessions across the links. A static split by source IP addresses, services, protocols, ... is usually easier to do. A dynamic, load-dependent balancing is usually harder to do.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to `what *kind* of router`.